# Reducing JPEG image quality without saving

Tags: c#, winforms, image, bitmap, image-quality

I am trying to programatically reduce the quality of an image in the fastest way possible. Right now, I am able to read image from `byte[]`, then as a `MemoryStream` read it to `Bitmap` and via `Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality` change its quality when saving to desired `20L`.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this without saving the whole image. Is there way to just change the bitmap `bmp1`, or create a new bitmap that would have the image quality reduced?

```
byte[] imageBytes = convertImageToByteArray(bmpScreenshot);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
using (Bitmap bmp1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(mem))
{

     ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
     ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = codecs[1];

     System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
     System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

     myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 20L);
     myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
     bmp1.Save(@"C:\TestPhotoQuality20L.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of saving `bmp1` to a file.  You can save it to another `MemoryStream`.  Then you could load a new bitmap from this `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 5):

David is right you can do like this.

```
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 20L);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp1.Save(ms, format);
Image imgImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```